# Accessing Data & Shell Within a Docker Container Running a Script

Tags: r, docker, containers

I am using Docker to run an Rscript which saves the output to the containers /home folder.
Is there some way I can:

A) Access a shell inside that container as the script is running? Trying to attach from another terminal just brings me to the same output as the 'taken-over' original terminal. I would like to access the file-system while it runs. -SOLVED

B) Grab the output saved into /home on the container and put it on my local machine? Does the data 'dissapear' once the container dies, or is there some way to access it after the script finishes and the container closes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) you can use `docker exec -it yourservername bash` assuming you have bash on the image

b) you can set-up a volume which maps a directory on your machine to a directory in the container. Everything that gets written out or changed in the volume will be available locally. Check out the [volume documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/)

You can also restart the container and pull out the output if you haven't removed the container.

Comment: The answer for (a) works just as I wanted, thanks. For (b), is that the only way to access the data? I was hoping to just get a shell to it and scp it over, after the Rscript finishes and the container exits. Is it possible to get the data at that point? Is it already gone?

Comment: No it should still be there. Just restart the container. Unless you rm the container after it stopped running.